# Process.Start() not spawning new process under the same user

Tags: c#, security, credentials, process.start, context-switch

I was always under the impression that when you're running a process as `(domain\user) mydomain\myuser`, when using `Process.Start()` it would start this new process using the same credentials - `mydomain\myuser`.

The issue I'm having is that my `Process.Start()` call seems to be creating a process under the SYSTEM account which is causing me permission issues in the started process (which must run under an admin account due to the work it does). If it changes things - I'm spawning this process (a custom built exe) from **within a windows installer**.

Any suggestions? I've read about windows group policies (possibly) having an impact on this, but if I'm honest, it's lost on me.

EDIT: a little snippet:

Where `exename` and `commandLine` are parameters for this method body:

```
ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exeName, commandLine);
procInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process process = Process.Start(procInfo);
Process.WaitForExit();
return process.ExitCode;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the original code isn't running as `System`?

Comment: Yep, 100% sure. I've checked this in two ways - one using the setup exe we have generated (and ensuring the user it's running under is me through the Task Manager). Also by running the MSI we have generated, using msiexec from the command prompt and forcing it to run with administrative rights under my username. Once the process.start() exe is started, it shows are being run by 'SYSTEM' in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either set procInfo.UseShellExecute to true, or execute cmd as a process with your exe as a parameter to the cmd command. When UseShellExecute is set to false, here are a lot of interesting side effects: [UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx)

Comment: I'll give the CMD idea a shot and get back in touch, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I am also running into this issue.  I am already calling to `cmd` with my exe as a parameter, and if I want error logging at all (by using `RedirectStandardError`, I can't set `UseShellExecute` to `true`.  What do I do from there?

Answer (score 3):

Your impression is true. Process.Start() will always start the new process under current user's credentials - unless you provide alternative credentials in the `ProcessStartInfo` or use one of the overloads that take credentials.

There must be another problem - share a snippet of your code.

**UPDATE**

OK! You did not mention anything about installer. All MSI installers will be running under system since they will be run by "**Windows Installer**" which you can check and they run under **SYSTEM**.

Comment: I've added a snippet from my method to start the process, it's nothign special though (and I've not parameterised any credentials). Thanks for the input so far, I'd be interested to hear any other thoughts you have.

Comment: Parts of the project are web based, but the installer and exe are just regular .Net code.

Comment: I said quite clearly (before any edits) "from within a windows installer.". On top of that, a setup.exe / MSI can run under any account.

Comment: So I must have missed that - this is something that you wanna highlight. I see that you have taken back your 10 points which is fine, but as I said again, MSI part of a setup always runs by the MSI installer service. You can verify this using various tools including process explorer where your process is shown under msiexec.exe and also whenever you run an installer, you see an msiexec.exe process oi started and after finishing, it disappears.