# Cannot restore nuget packages in C# when some packages in custom repository

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm writing a building application, this application can get the latest code from TFS, and then build them into DLLs. This application is hosted as ASP.NET web application, the application pool is run with my domain account.

Our code use [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/) to manage dependencies. And we have a local repository in our intranet, some dependencies **ONLY** in this local repository.

If I ran below command in the CMD,

```
D:\MyApplication\nuget.exe restore
```

Result is:

```
Installing 'My_Dependency_Only_In_Local_1 1.0.0'.
Installing 'My_Dependency_Only_In_Local_2 2.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'My_Dependency_Only_In_Local_1 1.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'My_Dependency_Only_In_Local_2 2.0.0'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
```

All the dependencies can be downloaded correctly. But in my C# code

```cs
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "nuget.exe"), "restore " + localProjectPath)
{
    WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError =  true,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    //Password = mypassword,
    //UserName = myusername,
    //Domain = mydomainname
};

var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit();

string errorText = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

unless I uncomment the `Password`, `UserName`, `Domain`, set the user info explicitly, I would got the below error:

```
Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'My_Dependency_Only_In_Local_1'.
Unable to find version '2.0.0' of package 'My_Dependency_Only_In_Local_2'.
```

I have no idea why this happened? This application is run by my account, and the `Process` I started might also run by my account, this command is works when running in CMD, but why not in my C# code?

Would you help me? Thank you in advanced.

PS: the nuget configuration is like below:

%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="intranet repository" value="http://our/local/nuget/repository" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="local cache" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

--

**UPDATE**:

I wrote a console application, rename it to nuget.exe, and overwrites the real one.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    File.WriteAllText("D:\\temp\\user.txt", System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
}
```

It shows, nuget.exe is run with my domain account.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4344953/264607

Comment: @BlackICE Thank you, I tried set UseShellExecute to true, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @quetzalcoatl 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646213/619424)

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    File.WriteAllText("D:\\temp\\path.txt", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
}
```

The output is `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming`
which means my config is not loaded.

After reading NuGet source code, I found the solution.

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads the machine wide settings.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// For example, if <paramref name="paths"/> is {"IDE", "Version", "SKU" }, then
/// the files loaded are (in the order that they are loaded):
///     %programdata%\NuGet\Config\IDE\Version\SKU\*.config
///     %programdata%\NuGet\Config\IDE\Version\*.config
///     %programdata%\NuGet\Config\IDE\*.config
///     %programdata%\NuGet\Config\*.config
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="fileSystem">The file system in which the settings files are read.</param>
/// <param name="paths">The additional paths under which to look for settings files.</param>
/// <returns>The list of settings read.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<Settings> LoadMachineWideSettings(
    IFileSystem fileSystem,
    params string[] paths)
{
    List<Settings> settingFiles = new List<Settings>();
    string basePath = @"NuGet\Config";
    string combinedPath = Path.Combine(paths);

    while (true)
    {   
        string directory = Path.Combine(basePath, combinedPath);

        // load setting files in directory
        foreach (var file in fileSystem.GetFiles(directory, "*.config"))

        ...
```

We can get the machine wide config file load path from comments.

So, the solution is

Copy config file from `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` to `C:\ProgramData\NuGet\Config\NuGet.Config`

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've confirmed that your one-liner fake-nuget is launched under correct account, please verify that:

- the 'user profile' is loaded for the app (TBO, I dont remember how, but it's late;) )
- %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config points where it should (related, easy to check)

It might happen that your child process is started with correct credentials, but **without** the user profile information. It is sometimes done to speed up the startup and to limit the process' interaction with user things like desktop layout, etc.

I imagine that if somehow the user-profile was skipped, then the %APPDATA% might point not where you have put the nuget's config.

I've often see services and workers use the

- Windows\System32\config\systemprofile
- Windows\SysWOW64..uhforgotthepart..\config\systemprofile

paths as their temporary homedirs. In such case, the APPDATA of your process would point there, and lookup for nuget config would fail.

Unfortunatelly, I don't know/remember how to force/skip the load-user-profile thing at the `ProcessStartInfo` level, but I roughly remember that `ShellExecute` suggested by BlackICE did load the profile, so it should have worked.. Still, be sure to check the APPDATA env variable, it might be it for some other reason.

edit: --
Sorry for being so chaotic. I've solved a completely different problem (but in the same problem domain) with builds and nuget's package restore, but I hardly can collect bits from memory. My goals were different: I wanted to prevent NuGet from reaching to internet and remote servers and to use only the local cache. So, almost the opposite of what you want. But all boiled down to NuGet not getting the config files. I couldn't "switch on" the profile-loading due to a certain setup of the CI server, so I solved it by putting the nuget config into appdata in syswow64\?\systemprofile on all of the related worker nodes (or system32\config\sysprofile on 32bit machines).